# Check if .NET 8 Bearer token is expired

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, bearer-token, asp.net-core-8

I am using .NET 8 Bearer Token not JWT token and I want to check if it is expired from my client app. Is there any way I can decode it or at least check if it is expired or not? Is there a way I can create a service that decode the token or check it is expired or no? Also, how can I know what is the secret key of the token?

Program.cs:

```
using EmployeeManagement.Database;
using EmployeeManagement.Entities;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Common;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Configrations;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Services.Department;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Services.Employee;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Services.UserRole;
using EmployeeManagement.Shared.Services.VacationRequests;
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? 
    throw new InvalidOperationException( "Connection string Not found")));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();


builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
});
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(
    typeof(EmployeeMapperConfig),
    typeof(UserRoleReMapperConfig),
    typeof(DepartmentMapperConfig),
    typeof(VacationRequestsMapperConfig),
    typeof(ApplicationUserMapperConfig)
 );
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRole, UserRoleService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDepartmentService, DepartmentServices>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVacationRequestsService, VacationRequestsService>();

builder.Services.AddFluentValidation();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<IAssemblyMarker>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();

app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Angular app:

```
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
import { EmployeeManagementWebAPIService } from '../api/employee-management-web-api.service';
import { RefreshRequest } from '../model/refresh-request';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export const tokenInterceptorInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  console.log("tokenInterceptorInterceptor+++");
  let authService = inject(EmployeeManagementWebAPIService);
  let router = inject(Router);
  const AccessToken = localStorage.getItem('AccessToken');
  const RefreshToken = localStorage.getItem('RefreshToken');
  if (AccessToken) {
    console.log("tokenInterceptorInterceptor++999+"+AccessToken);
   try{
    let decodedToken = jwtDecode(AccessToken);
    console.log("decodedToken+++" + decodedToken);
    const isExpired =
      decodedToken && decodedToken.exp
        ? decodedToken.exp < Date.now() / 1000
        : false;

    if (isExpired) {
      console.log('token is expired');
      const refreshRequest: RefreshRequest = {
        refreshToken: RefreshToken,
      };
      authService.refreshPost(refreshRequest).subscribe(
        (newToken: any) => {
          localStorage.setItem('AccessToken', newToken);
          req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${newToken}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set content type here
            },
          });
          console.log('Refresh token successful:', newToken);
        },
        (error) => {
          // Handle error response here
          localStorage.removeItem("AccessToken");
          router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          console.error('Error refreshing token:', error);
        }
      );
    }
    else{
      console.error('Token not expired');
    }
   }catch(e){
      console.log("invalid token" , e);
      localStorage.removeItem("AccessToken");
      router.navigateByUrl('/login');
   }
  }
  else{
    console.error('Token Not found');
    router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }
  return next(req);
};
```

my login response:

```
{
  "tokenType": "Bearer",
  "accessToken": "",
  "expiresIn": 3600,
  "refreshToken": ""
}
```

Comment: In your code, I can't see how you generate the token you want to validate. It should not be necessary to decode the token to validate if it is expired. BTW you included this ".AddJwtBearer()" in your code, which means you allow JWT and that will check by default if the token is expired or not. Remember JWT and Bearer are the same thing (short story). If you want to know if your token is JWT, you can use jwt.io, paste your token there and you will see